# How to Display Dynamic SUBMENU in menu in WPF application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, submenu

i am trying to bind a list to menu in WPF using vb.net.
what i had tried was.
in xaml design:

```
<Window x:Class="content"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="content" Height="850" Width="725" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" >
    <Grid>


        <Menu Name="menu_wpf" >     </Menu>       

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code behind:

```
 Private Sub content_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Dim lst_menu As List(Of wpf_appBAL)

    Using BAL As New wpf_appBAL
        lst_company = BAL.fill_menu(BAL)  

        menu_wpf.ItemsSource = lst_company
        menu_wpf.DisplayMemberPath = "Quantity"


    End Using

End Sub
```

it displays the menu correctly..

Now i need to add submenus to the menu - how do i achieve that? plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `Menu` looks like this:

```
<Menu Name="menu_wpf">
        <MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" Header="Quantity">
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

And delete `menu_wpf.DisplayMemberPath = "Quantity"` in .vb file.

Comment: I had done it. But it shows  error "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource." while i am trying to assign ItemsSource as List.